# Angular2 RxJS Observable.fromEvent(..) .map doesn't look available

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs

following the [autocomplete example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/autocomplete/autocomplete.js) with RxJS. I suspect that the Observable i am using may be different from Observable in this example?

Here is how I set it up:

```
@ViewChild('searchInput') input: ElementRef;
...
var keyups = Observable.fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup')
// this returns FromEventObservable instead of Observable which may be the reason?
```

at this point, I can call .subscribe and see the events flow in:

```
keyups.subscribe( e => console.log(e));
```

however this does not show anything **** :

```
  keyups.map( e => console.log('e ', e) );
```

my imports look like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

but i've also experimented with individual imports:

```
 import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

package.json

```
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an Observable to actually do something, you need to subscribe to it.

```
keyups.map( e => console.log('e ', e) ).subscribe(...);
```

But the `map` operator is meant to map from one value to another. So after `keyups.map(e => console.log('e ', e))` you get an Observable of whatever `console.log` returns - which is likely `undefined` and doesn't make sense. It may work nontheless, bu you'd better use `.do` if you just need some side-effects like logging

Comment: if you look at the link i referenced they are using map to get the target value, they are doing: fromEvent(..).map(..).filter(..).debounce(..).distinctUntilChanged(). This is what i'm trying to replicate. 
I know I can subscribe, but not sure how to then translate that to filter and the rest of this example

Comment: Sonic, in the example that you referenced, they `subscribe()` to the `searcher` variable, which is an `Observable` resulted by an operation in the `keyup`: 

`var searcher = keyup.flatMapLatest(searchWikipedia);`